# Updating output value of ControlValueAccessor in writeValue

Tags: angular

I'm creating my first form element using ControlValueAccessor, and it's working for the most part, except for when the initial value passed is invalid.

My writeValue method converts the input into something my element expects, and if the values don't match expected values, leaves it as the property default.

```
selected: { hour: string, minutes: string, meridiem: string } = { hour: null, minutes: null, meridiem: null }

writeValue(value: string | { hour: string, minutes: string, meridiem: string }) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null && typeof value === "string") {
        let matches = value.trim().match(/(1?\d):?([0-5]\d)\s*([aApP][mM])/);
        if (matches) {
            this.selected = { hour: matches[1], minutes: matches[2], meridiem: matches[3].toLowerCase()};
        }
    }
    this.propagateChange(this.outputDisplay());
}
```

The problem I'm having is `propogateChange` doesn't seem to trigger? The form's initial value remains, and if the user doesn't change the element, the invalid value remains. Is there some way for me to change the initial value?

Comment: Do you mean `writeValue` triggers but `propagateChange` method don't get called?

Comment: Yes. I subscribed to my field, but I don't see the value update after `writeValue` fires, only after I interact with my element.

Comment: sounds like a change detection issue, try triggering it manually on init